# Trouble with getting web page's HTML code from my C# program

Tags: c#, .net

The problem:
I want to scrap some data from certain webpage (I have administrative access) and to store some information in db for later analysis.
Sounds easy, right?
I've decided to make simple console prototype and code look something like this:

```
string uri =  @"http://s7.iqstreaming.com:8044/admin.cgi";
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

if(request == null)
{
     Console.WriteLine(":( This shouldn't happen!");
     Console.ReadKey();
}

request.ContentType = @"text/html";
request.Accept = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myID", "myPass");

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream());

     while (!reader.EndOfStream)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
     }

     reader.Close();
     response.Close();
}
```

This code works on most other sites, but here I get errors 404 (most of the time), 502 or timeout.
I've consulted with Firebug (I've took Accept and compression info from there) but to no avail.
Using Win-forms and webBrowser control as an alternative is not an option (at least for now).

P.S.
Same thing happens when I try to get HTML from http://s7.iqstreaming.com:8044/index.html (doesn't need credentials).

Comment: "404 (most of the time)" - does it sometimes work or does it never work and you get other errors some of the time?

Comment: I gave that 2nd address a quick test and it says `"The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine"`

Comment: Your app must allow unsafe header parsing. In your config file you must set <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>.

"404 most of the time" means it never worked so far (it throws exception on request.GetResponse()) and most of the time it results with error 404 and sometimes in 502.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related with `User-Agent`.
This may solve it

```
request.UserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.78 Safari/535.11";
```